# CentOS /usr/local/lib system wide $LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, environment-variables, path

I install custom software in `/usr/local/lib`. How do I set the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in CentOS 6 system-wide to use `/usr/local/lib`. I realize there may be more than one way. What's the simplest and most standard way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add it in `/etc/bashrc`, say, at the end.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: While this works, for a proper installation, see @Olivier S's answer below.

Comment: Also, OP probably wanted `$PATH` to refer to `/usr/local/bin` instead of  `/usr/local/lib`. I agree that's not the original question, but custom software is standardly installed in `/usr/local` prefix with binaries in `/usr/local/bin`, libraries in `/usr/local/lib`, etc.

Answer (score 97):

You can edit the file `/etc/ld.so.conf` and add your path `/usr/local/lib` to it
or create a new file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` like `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/usrlocal.conf`
and put only the following line in it

```
/usr/local/lib
```

Then run `ldconfig -v` as root, and you're done.

Comment: +1: imho this is a much cleaner solution than the accepted one.

Comment: Dare I call this method "proper"?

Comment: I had to run this as root (via sudo)

Comment: Is this what you meant to say: "you can edit /etc/ld.so.conf and /usr/local/lib" ?

Comment: But after doing this I am getting error `/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pycurl.so: undefined symbol: CRYPTO_set_locking_callback` while using yum. What to do?

Comment: This doesn't work for me (CentOS 6).  Library file still not found.