# Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH not enough?

Tags: linux, centos, environment-variables, dependencies, libraries

I've edited my `/etc/bashrc` to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` like in [my previous question that I asked](https://serverfault.com/questions/372987/centos-usr-local-lib-system-wide-ld-library-path). However it does not seem to be taking effect. Even though `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does show my modifications. And running my program: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib" ./test.cgi` explicity does work. Do I need to reboot the system? What's going on?

Comment: You don't need to reboot.  The updated /etc/bashrc will be read when the user logs in again.  Can you show the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and how you are running your executable?

Comment: @cjc updated. Running with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib" ./test.cgi ` works `./test.cgi` does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `export` the variable.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
./test.cgi
```

Your formulation `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib" ./test.cgi` sets the variable in the current shell.  If you're just running `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ; ./test.cgi` you will set it in the current shell, but not in the child process ./test.cgi.

From the `bash` man page:

```
export:
        The supplied names are marked for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands.
```

Comment: Your answer to my other question was incorrect because this works! :/

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot to specify the `export` in bashrc.

Answer (score 3):

Try to run `ldconfig -v` to rebuild the library cache.

Comment: This was not the problem, but then again I just rebooted so it was probably already done.