# How do I configure FreeNX APPLICATION_LIBRARY_PRELOAD to the correct directory?

Tags: centos, freenx

The FreeNX server gives the following error on startup:
 `APPLICATION_LIBRARY_PRELOAD [...] /usr/lib/libX11.so could not be found`.

The thing is that /usr/lib/libX11.so library is already installed, except on my system it's in the directory `/usr/lib/NX/lib`.
How do I point NX to the right directory?

There is no APPLICATION_LIBRARY_PRELOAD in `/etc/nxserver/node.conf`. How can I fix this directory problem and not mess up SELinux contexts (thinking to just add links everywhere NX is looking)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question only because I happened to find a 4th solution--a needle in the haystack. I did some `ldd` testing on `/usr/bin/nx*`, which strangely didn't return the information matching my dynamic libraries that I was expecting. `grep` on the same files just happened to find this block in `/usr/bin/nxloadconfig`:

```
#########################################################################
# INTERNAL STUFF
# DO NOT TOUCH unless you REALLY know what you are doing
#########################################################################

NX_VERSION=3.2.0-74-SVN
NX_LICENSE="OS (GPL, using backend: %BACKEND%)"

# Where can different nx components be found
NX_DIR=/usr
PATH_BIN=$NX_DIR/bin # if you change that, be sure to also change the public keys
PATH_LIB=$NX_DIR/lib
NX_ETC_DIR=/etc/nxserver
NX_SESS_DIR=/var/lib/nxserver/db
NX_HOME_DIR=/var/lib/nxserver/home

# Advanced users ONLY
AGENT_LIBRARY_PATH="" #Calculated
PROXY_LIBRARY_PATH="" #Calculated
APPLICATION_LIBRARY_PATH="" #Calculated
APPLICATION_LIBRARY_PRELOAD="" #Calculated

# the name of the authorized keys file for ssh
SSH_AUTHORIZED_KEYS="authorized_keys2"
```

I manually edited `PATH_LIB=$NX_DIR/lib` to `PATH_LIB=$NX_DIR/lib/NX/lib` and now the only missing files are *actually* missing (libXcomp.so.2)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the description in your question your problem isn't that the library isn't installed, it's that `ld` (the dynamic linker) doesn't know where it is: CentOS expects the library to be in `/usr/lib/` but it's really in `/usr/lib/NX/lib`.

There are a few ways to fix this:

1. Set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to include your non-standard library paths before starting the NX server.
2. Create symlinks from the `/usr/lib/NX/lib/*` libraries to `/usr/lib`
3. (The "Right Way") Tell `ld` about your non-standard library paths so it searches them.

---

Options 1 and 2 should be pretty self-explanatory.
For more information on Option 3, [check out this answer on a similar question](https://serverfault.com/a/372998/32986).

Comment: Something like the _third block_ from [Setting Oracle Environment Variables](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/sect-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Setting_Up_a_Working_Environment_for_Oracle-Setting_Oracle_Environment_Variables.html) and the _last comment_-- since nxserver has its own home directory?

Comment: @xtian Yes, provided you always `su` to the NX user before starting the server, but I would *really* suggest option 3 rather than option 1. It's a more proper solution, and works no matter what user NX is launched as.